# Existe algum metodo ou forma para fazer isso?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Sou novo em programação, tenho um pouco de experiência com HTML (consequêntemente JavaScript), e preciso de alguma coisa mais ou menos assim:

Algo que "leia" um arquivo html e pegue alguma informação direto do source.

Por exemplo:

```
<div class=exemplo>
    <ol>
      <li>ex1</li>
      <li>ex2</li>
      <li>ex3</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Em um HTML e retorne o que eu quero que ele retorne.

É possivel fazer isso via JS?

Desde já, Obrigado.

Comment: Podes exlicar melhor esta frase: "Algo que "leia" um arquivo html e pegue alguma informação direto do source."? O que queres dizer com `source`? queres fazer isso dinamicamente ou queres que o utilizador escolha o ficheiro? e queres um ficheiro local ou remoto?

Comment: Desculpa, explica melhor também esta frase: "e retorne o que eu quero que ele retorne".

Comment: Remoto, eu acho. mais ou menos assim, o programa gera uma pagina (Como uma busca randomica no google), visita ela (sem a parte gráfica) e retorna oque é especificado.

Comment: E esse site remoto aceita CORS? (pedidos de outros dominios). Não podes fazer isso no PHP ou Node.js (para ser com JavaScript mas no lado do servidor)?

Comment: Como eu to querendo fazer isso com o Youtube, que é da google, provavelmente sim.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors

Comment: Que informação específica quer obter do Youtube?

Comment: Quero as views dos videos encontrados.

http://i.imgur.com/S5ydFN9.png
Como se pode ver aqui, todas essas listas, são os resultados, e dentro de cada resultado, tem as views. Além do href
Então resumindo, algo que extraia o href e as views.

Comment: Procure por crawlers ou web spiders.

Comment: @DiegoMachado Como eu faço para escolher seu comentário como resposta? Sou novo por aqui. Valeu pela dica! Existem centenas de web crawlers por aí. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Ao lado do comentário possui uma seta para cima. Mas você pode também responder a esse tópico fazendo uma citação ao comentário e marcar sua resposta como resolvido. Abraços!

Comment: @DiegoMachado e MateusMercer, para aceitar como resposta o comentário o correto é escrever esse comentário como resposta para que possa ser clicado na opção aceitar, o voto da setinha para cima apenas indica que o comentário foi bom para esclarecer/solucionar o problema.

Comment: Ok, está escrito como resposta